# Jager with istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, jaeger, distributed-tracing

I am facing difficulty in working with jaeger and Istio.

Can anyone please describe the steps that are to be followed in configuring jaeger and istio for any demo application. I have tried a few blogs and sites but unfortunately, nothing worked for me. if anyone could help me in this that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have followed the official documentation of the jager with istio.

If you are using the helm chart make the following changes required.

```
In main values.yaml file
tracing:
  enabled: true

In tracing/values.yaml
provider: jaeger
```

Export the dashboard via Kube port-forward or ingress.

Official Documentation.
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/distributed-tracing/jaeger/

NOTE: The important thing by default jaeger will trace something like 0.1% request i.e. 1 request out of 100 so put a lot of requests only then you can see a trace in UI.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  can you please list the paths of those two values.yaml files. As we have found only one values.yaml file in the following path i.e /istio-1.2.2/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/.

Comment: istio-1.2.2/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/tracing/values.yaml